# App crashes when using bitmap and mat with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap, mat

[image]So I would like to start developing apps using `OpenCV`. I want try something simple, read an image, convert it to grayscale and then display it.

When I read it and convert it using Mat, the app works fine. When I read it and display it using Bitmaps it works fine as well. When I combine both, read the image using mat, convert it to bitmap it crashes. I don't have a `logcat` because I can't play the app straight away from the computer so I have to send the `.apk` every time ...
I downloaded LogcatBrowser and took a screenshot of what I obtained ...

`MainAcvitity.Java` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

         private Bitmap mBitmap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


        private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {


            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                if (status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS ) {

                    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_camera);
                    Mat m = Highgui.imread("gph.jpg");
                    //Imgproc.cvtColor(m, m, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.cols(),  m.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(m, mBitmap);
                    img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

                } else {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onResume() {;
            super.onResume();
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_5,this, mLoaderCallback);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please find a way to post LogCat, so we can help. There are LogCat viewing apps in Play Store.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that ! I added a screenshort, thank you !

Comment: When it Crashes, it should show some sort of Stack Trace, can You find anything relevant in LogCat ?

Comment: Yeah I can't fin anything on this one really apart from that red line. Could you suggest any good app for viewing the LogCat ?

Comment: Best way would be to connect phone to computer. There should be much more in the LogCat than that. Otherwise, [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en) has a LogCat viewer which at least works.

Comment: not sure about that bitmap stuff but probably ARGB_8888 means you create a 4 channel 32 bit elements image. later you want to map a 8 bit single channel openCV mat to it, I guess that Is your problem. Try to cvtColor CV_BGR2BGRA instead of 2GRAY or try 2ARGB if it exists

Comment: So you're suggesting to modify the grayscale conversion line but the app crashes even without that line ...

Comment: if you remove that line you try to map a 24 bit BGR image to a 32 bit ARGB image... did you try to adjust the line according to my previous comment?

Comment: So I tried both, with or without conversion and crashed again. I used Config.RGB_565 without conversion OR cvtColor CV_BGR2BGRA  with Config.ARGB_8888 for the bitmap ...and nothing

Comment: are you able to create some kind of output to verify the line where it crashes and print m.channels etc?

Comment: So I managed to get the admin rights to install a driver and to be able to play the app when my phone is connected to the computer. I have access to Eclipse Logcat. It seems that 'm.cols' and 'm.rows' are NULL...